# How to file patent in India

Tags: patent-applications

I'm from India, And have some uniq prototype work that I want to patent. Does any one have idea about filing an patent in India!

Answer (score 1):

The Indian Patent Office should be your first port of call.

Check out their [basic manual chapter 3, sections 1 to 6](http://www.ipindia.nic.in/ipr/patent/manual/HTML%20AND%20PDF/Manual%20of%20Patent%20Office%20Practice%20and%20Procedure%20-%20html/Chapter%203.htm), and follow the instructions.